# Send variables to other classes

Tags: c#

Can I have a function that checks if true or false and send my verbal to other classes?

I tried:

```
public class Func
{
    public static bool CheckDate(string number)
    {
        string new_number = number.ToString();
        if (new_number.Length==8)
        {
           string yyyy = new_number.Substring(0, 4);
           string mm = new_number.Substring(4, 2);
           string dd = new_number.Substring(6, 2);
           return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to send the verbal `yyyy`, `mm`, `dd` to my `Program.cs` class.

What should I do?

Comment: Please choose a more meaningful title for your question.

Comment: Yes you can send them. Are you asking about returning multiple values from your CheckDate?

Answer (score 7):

Don't reinvent wheels, use the [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method which is built specifically for this purpose. Forget about regexes and substrings when you are dealing with dates in the .NET framework:

```
public static bool CheckDate(string number, out DateTime date)
{
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(number, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
}
```

And now as you can see defining the `CheckDate` becomes kinda meaningless because it already exists in the BCL. You would simply use it like this:

```
string number = "that's your number coming from somewhere which should be a date";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    number, 
    "dd/MM/yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out date
))
{
    // the number was in the correct format 
    // => you could use the days, months, from the date variable which is now a DateTime

    string dd = date.Day.ToString();
    string mm = date.Month.ToString();
    string yyyy = date.Year.ToString();
    // do whatever you intended to do with those 3 variables before
}
else
{
    // tell the user to enter a correct date in the format dd/MM/yyyy
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Since I got a remark in the comments section that I am not actually answering the question, you could use a similar approach to the one I recommend. But please, promise me you will **never write a code like this**, it's just for illustration of the TryXXX pattern.

define a model:

```
public class Patterns
{
    public string DD { get; set; }
    public string MM { get; set; }
    public string YYYY { get; set; }
}
```

and then modify your CheckDate method so that it sends an out parameter:

```
public static bool CheckDate(string number, out Patterns patterns)
{
    patterns = null;
    string new_number = number.ToString();
    if (new_number.Length == 8)
    {
       Patterns = new Patterns
       {
           YYYY = new_number.Substring(0, 4),
           MM = new_number.Substring(4, 2),
           DD = new_number.Substring(6, 2)
       }
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which you could use like this:

```
string number = "that's your number coming from somewhere which should be a date";
Patterns patterns;
if (CheckDate(numbers, out patterns)
{
    string dd = patterns.DD;
    string mm = patterns.MM;
    string yyyy = patterns.YYYY;
    // do whatever you intended to do with those 3 variables before
}
else
{
    // tell the user to enter a correct date in the format dd/MM/yyyy
}
```

Comment: it is a very good answer. It doesn't answer his question, though :)

Comment: yeah, so 4 upvotes for an answer that actually doesn’t solve anything; you’re smart.

Comment: I have updated my answer to illustrate how the OP could solve his original problem. But of course you should absolutely never write a code like the one shown in my updated answer. It's just for illustration purposes. What you should know is that StackOverflow is not for just blindly answering questions. It's for providing the best alternative to the problem that the OP is actually trying to solve. And in case you guys didn't understand what the actual problem here is, let me tell you: he is trying to parse a string into a date instance and use the day, month and year if this parsing succeed.

Comment: It's just that the OP was not aware of the existence of the TryParseExact method which is meant to do exactly that and he started writing his own method. So I provided him with the actual solution to **his original problem** which I repeat once again is not `Send variables to other classes` as stated in his question title. It's just that he doesn't know it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `CheckDate` function’s aim is to check if a date is valid. Don’t introduce crappy side effects: write another function that actually sends your stuff to the object you want.

If you want to check if a string is a date, do it in `CheckDate`.

When you know a string is a date, extract the date elements you want from it through such a `ExtractDateElem` function, but please, no side-effects.

Answer (score -1):

you have to declare your variables as below...

```
 public static  string yyyy;
 public static  string mm ;
 public static  string dd ;
```

Or

```
 protected static  string yyyy;
 protected static  string mm ;
 protected static  string dd ;
```

as per your need and depends where your **program.cs** file is...